# How to git diff multiple sibling git folders

Tags: git, git-submodules

For reason I can't change, I have N sibling folders.
Each of which is a differente git repo.
When developing a feature I have to touch files in every folder (more or less).

There is a way to recap all those diffs? Can I make those N folder 'submodule' of a MAIN git repo (local only one) and commit/push/pull each git repo on its own like usual?

...

Comment: You can write script for this purpose.

Comment: yes, ok, I was looking for some git-magic stuff ^_^

Comment: There is http://marc.info/?m=134809388221332 though does not seem to be much simpler than "write a script". At least it should provide consistent response to `git diff`.